# Access encrypted boot drive partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, encryption

I installed Ubuntu on a blank hard drive, and selected the option to install the OS as encrypted. Later, I partitioned the drive and installed a second copy of Ubuntu (unencrypted). The drive structure now looks like this:

[image: partitioned drives]

Partition 5:

- The original install (encrypted)
- Contents: Ext4 (version 1.0) Mounted at /home
- Partition Type: Linux (Bootable)
- When I select 'Edit Partition' from within the  application 'Disks' I have the check box 'bootable' checked.

Partition 6:

- The second install (unencrypted, other then the home dir)
- Contents: Ext4 (version 1.0) Mounted at Filesystem Root
- Partition Type: Linux
- Bootable is not checked

As of now, each time I boot up the system I am only able to login to the Partition 6. The option to login to my original (Partition 5) is not presented. Could someone please assist me in accessing Partition 5?